# Finding the derivative- is my answer correct? Is the method correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, chain-rule

Question - find the derivative of $y$ with respect to $z$
$$y=  2^{z^3} $$

So what I’d do is
Differentiate boths sides of the equation so
$$\frac{dy}{dz}= \frac{d(2^{z^3 })}{dz}$$
Then I applied the chain rule by assuming,
$$ u=z^3$$

which resulted in
$$ 2^{z^3}\ln2\frac{dz^3}{dz}$$

Using the power rule I finally got the answer to be
$$ 3z^2\cdot2^{z^3}\ln2$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Is it meant to be $2z^3$ or $2^{z^3}$? If the latter, write this as 2^{z^3} in Mathjax

Comment: No, your answer, as written, is not correct.

Comment: But you are close. Apply the exponential rule and then only use the chain rule.

Comment: It is correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule in this case gives: $$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dz}$$

You set $u=z^3$, so $y=2^u$, then $\frac{du}{dz}=3z^2$ and $\frac{dy}{du}=2^u\cdot \ln (2)$

Combining the two and substituting out $u$ we get $$\frac{du}{dz}\cdot\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{dy}{dz}=3\ln (2) \cdot 2^{z^3}\cdot z^2$$
which you got.

Comment: This is also the OP's answer...

Comment: Yes. However, I felt their solution wasn't quite as fleshed out as some examiners might want it to be.

Comment: Could I not simplify this to be, 3 ⋅ (2^{z^3}z^2ln(2)?$$

Comment: Yes, but it's good practice to keep the co-efficient (here $3\ln 2$) together.

Comment: Could writing $\ln(8)$ instead of $3\ln(2)$ be better?

Comment: Either works fine, as they represent the same value